# Checking Prime Numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, algorithm

Take the following problem: "how many numbers are in a given range of integers, from which both their sum of digits and the sum of its square are prime?"

I was watching around [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/puzzle-sum-of-the-digits-is-prime-or-not) I found an interesting question and tried to solve it.

So one can check `prime numbers` in a ordinary fashion, i.e. using a `for` loop from `2` to `i` and check for divisibility.

The interesting thing is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/8339/12649). `BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft` suggests a trick: "Since you only need to sieve to the square root of the number you're testing for primality, you only need to run your sieve from 3 to*`sqrt(⌈log10(B)⌉*81)`".

I have a question regarding implementation of `Sieve of Eratosthenes`.
what is the size of `boolean array`, which contains numbers to process for sieve.? can somebody write a code or any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes using Java: [link](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/PrimeSieve.java.html).

For the second part of your questions see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/puzzle-sum-of-the-digits-is-prime-or-not) link:

> "The maximum sum of squares-of-digits of an n-digit number is n*9*9 = n*81. The number of digits in a number B is ⌈log10(B)⌉.  Since you only need to sieve to the square root of the number you're testing for primality, you only need to run your sieve from 3 to sqrt(⌈log10(B)⌉*81). Even for B = 1 billion, this means the max you need to sieve to is 28."

Comment: I understand the algorithm correctly by seeing the implementation. thank you very much. however i still didn't understand the next line. _Since you only need to sieve to the square root of the number you're testing for primality, you only need to run your sieve from 3 tosqrt(⌈log10(B)⌉*81)_